# Mailbridge nonSSL to SSL Server

Tags: c#, email, ssl

i try to write a "Mailbridge" (i know the buffer is too small for full Mails) for old Applications without SSL Support. (The application connect to "localhost"/my Server  and my Server to the real SSL Mailserver) My Problem:

```
{
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();


        TcpClient sslmail = new TcpClient();
        SslStream sslStream;

            sslmail.Connect(server, sslport);
            sslStream = new SslStream(sslmail.GetStream());

            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];




            int bytes=0;

            while((sslmail.Connected) && (tcpClient.Connected))
            { 

        try
        {

            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


              bytes=sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            MessageBox.Show("To Client: "+Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();




             Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);



               bytes=clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               MessageBox.Show("To Server: "+Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

            sslStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            sslStream.Flush();
}
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }


                /////////////////////////////////////
            }

            sslmail.Close();
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
```

The connection works:

```
To Client: +OK POP server ready H migmx018 0LaT8c-1ZFbyb06RD-00m4N0
To Server: USER xxxxxx
To Client: +OK password required for user "xxxxxx"
```

Thats all, now it "hangs" at

```
bytes=clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

testet with Windows Live Mail, then i used a own simple Mailapplication, but if i send "PASS mypass" the Server returns "-ERR unknown command" (used Server: pop.gmx.net)
(Direct Connections with Windows Livemail to the Server working without problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved the Problem, the following code works, but a bit slow for big Mails, because of the Timeouts

```
{
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();



            TcpClient sslmail = new TcpClient();
            SslStream sslStream;

                sslmail.Connect(server, sslport);
                sslStream = new SslStream(sslmail.GetStream());

                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);
            int buffersize=1024;    
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];




                int bytes=0;

                while((sslmail.Connected) && (tcpClient.Connected))
                { 

            try
            {

                Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


                try
                {
                    sslStream.ReadTimeout = 100;
                    bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


                    clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    clientStream.Flush();


                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    //timeout, server is waiting for client     
                }


                Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);



                 try
                 {
                     clientStream.ReadTimeout = 100;
                     bytes = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);



                     sslStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                     sslStream.Flush();
                 }
                 catch (Exception err)
                 {
                 //timeout, client is waiting for Server
                 }
}
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                sslmail.Close();
                tcpClient.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }


                    /////////////////////////////////////
                }

                sslmail.Close();
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
```